# How to find newly added or modified files in a deep folder structure?

Tags: windows-7, backup, file-transfer

I have a deep folder structure that organizes the files that I download from internet. There are about 15 high level folders and each on an average has 12 sub folders. Some are nested further. When I download, I save directly into the proper folders. The structure grows as well, needing new folders to be created as necessary.

How can I find the files that are recently added, anywhere in the folder structure?

The reason I really need this for is this. I maintain multiple backups of thousands of these ever growing files, in external hdd and pen drives, with the same folder structure. I want to quickly copy-paste the newly saved files from my pc to backup locations. The built in Windows 7 copy does allow to skip copying files that exist already etc but I find attempting to copy-paste thousands of files and then waiting for the prompt to show up really tedious.

As a supplementary question, is there a tool that would copy only the newly saved files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal windows search function will allow you to search on `date created` or `date modified`.  This will allow you to see what has been created on what day or since a specific day.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work earlier, before I posted this rather embarrassingly long question! Thanks.

Comment: No worries! good luck!  Also, take a look at robocopy: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx It should do what you're looking for.

Comment: rsync and robocopy are good for quick syncing.